# Renaming a public event with Metadata.xml

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to bind a Java Library (.jar) to be used with Mono for Android following [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29) documentation. Compiling the project results in 1 error:

> 'MoveAnimation.MoveAnimation': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type.

I understand the error and why it's happening, but I can't seem to find the right xpath to rename the event within the Metadata.xml file.

I've tried:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.namespace.android']/class[@name='MoveAnimation']/event[@name='MoveAnimation']" name="managedName">MoveAnimationEvent</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.namespace.android']/class[@name='MoveAnimation.MoveAnimation']" name="managedName">MoveAnimationEvent</attr>
```

and many other combinations.

What's the right way to rename the event?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the full path to any method or property by looking at the managed callable wrapper generated in the `obj\bin\Debug\Generated` folder after you build. Each class member is decorated with a comment that gives the exact path of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to fix the problem

NewNameOfClass

This will change the name of the class so your property name can remain the same.

Here is some more helpful information on this.

http://holisticware.net/HolisticWare/Know-How/development/Mobile/android/mono-for-android-monodroid/binding-projects.aspx